# CSS blocking the links to be clicked

Tags: css, z-index

I am creating an angular App. I created views of the applications separately. When I integrated the views with the main App some of the links that were previously working have become Un-clickable.

I have done a lot of research and my best guess is that somewhere there is an issue with z-index. The links are hidden under some layer.

Here is the link to application.

http://ec2-54-165-82-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com/#!/user/profile

user: tade@gleepost.com
pass: 1234567

The picture illustrates the area where the issue is occurring.

[image]

Please help me out here. Its a quick fix but can't figure out how.

Comment: Firebug is your friend of this sort of thing

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicions are correct. The element `.contentArea` has a negative `z-index` value. It is declared twice.

Line 184

```
.contentArea {
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:15%;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:45px;
    /* z-index:-5; */
    position:relative;
}
```

Line 286

```
.groupAreaA {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    /* z-index: -5; */
}
```

Comment: but because of this my profile drop down is now hidden under the nav. Click "Evan Zuckerberg" in the top bar and you will see. I am trying to assign it some higher z-index but it does not do the trick

Comment: @TalhaMasood You could remove the relative positioning on both of the elements in the answer above.